# Is it possible to create a custom Lookup of type Customer in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have one custom entity in CRM 2011. My requirement is to create a lookup field(say Customer) for this entity like Out of the Box Customer in Case entity which is pointing to both Account and Contact records. How can I create this custom Customer field?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this is not possible. For custom lookups you have to decide which entity is the target.

In your case, you would have to define two lookups (one for each type). This is by the way the same behavior which is used by the customer lookup. They are only hidden from your eyes.

If you want to see this feature in future versions, you could support these requests on connect:

- [Custom Composite Lookups (multi-relationship in 1 lookup)](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/685374/custom-composite-lookups-multi-relationship-in-1-lookup)
- [Give me the ability to create a lookup on the 'Customer' entity](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/678425/give-me-the-ability-to-create-a-lookup-on-the-customer-entity)
- [Expand the 'Customer' entity to other entities](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/678426/expand-the-customer-entity-to-other-entities)

Comment: I tried reverse engineering this by adding entries to the attributelookup table; however, I ran into an error when activating the code.  So, although I could get CRM to show the additional entities I wanted added, I could not get the additional entities to work =/  I'd love to see someone get this to work, since I'm convinced that MS has made it possible through SQL tweaking; I also know that I can't justify diving further into at the moment.